# How to resolve Sklearn KNN Not fitted Error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn, sklearn-pandas

I try to implement some KNN classification for some RMS_features which I extracted from some sensor data. 
The labeled sensor data looks like this:

```
RMS_x   RMS_y   RMS_z   RMS_euclidian   labels
0.137221994086372451    0.141361458137922474    0.373367693426083891    0.422156809730974525    1
0.653967197231734354    0.523601431745291057    0.857427471986578205    1.19875494747598155 0
0.547301970096429224    0.510460963300706561    0.851980921284600901    1.13401116915058431 1
0.200317415034924756    0.137815296326320835    0.353579753893964288    0.429113930129869203    1
0.802069910360720617    0.752364652538367706    0.909861874144165417    1.42731122797950638 1
0.879041000013726426    0.746218766636731257    0.88728425792715937 1.45493260385191925 1
0.144637160351783728    0.117846411938445361    0.445677862167030925    0.483152607141023704    0
0.142457833655985133    0.0730350196404254831   0.287273765845172724    0.328868613593180703    0
0.0866202724953416131   0.0616184109162635982   0.266749047302988929    0.287149707309732383    1
0.839153663116914195    0.714433206853633651    0.785256227002287477    1.35322615235723642 0
0.112852384316477455    0.113895536346822021    0.298205076872631036    0.338576611298323393    1
1.03867993617356702 0.860906249377046295    0.826493656885982309    1.58212115367273398 1
1.08309298701834544 0.777872116663065438    0.107827834335941439    1.33783492638956725 0
0.269545256634713071    0.173020210546502379    0.396383770058648055    0.509618221610782407    0
2.82554170256769766 2.75559888003772846 2.72907654403846411 4.79842368740352843 0
0.956220220626555983    0.849082605233856036    1.16655931706066363 1.73094165732610805 0
0.393801166109265799    0.283932207763270439    0.591509176401210479    0.765231966661861884    0
0.809556622304495543    0.540659060535479075    0.909773758642383967    1.3324347775296399  0
```

My code for extracting the data and using KNN on it looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.exceptions import NotFittedError


def file_read_in(filename):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t', low_memory=False, skiprows=0)  # use seperations character e.g '\t' ';'
    data = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x), axis=0)

    return data


def knn_alg(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, N):
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=N)
    knn.fit = (X_train, y_train)

    try:
        knn.predict(X_test)
    except NotFittedError as e:
        print(repr(e))

    # print(knn.predict(X_test))


def split_dataset(X, y):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1, stratify=y)
    return X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test


def main():
    filename_labeled = "labeled_session_data/out/labeled.csv"
    filename_unlabeled = "unlabeled_session_data/out/unlabeled.csv"
    # column_nr = 4
    data_labeled = file_read_in(filename_labeled)
    data_unlabeled = file_read_in(filename_unlabeled)

    X = data_labeled.drop(columns=['labels'])
    y = data_labeled['labels'].values

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = split_dataset(X, y)
    n_neighbors = 3

    print("X_train " + "\n" + str(X_train))
    print("X_test " + "\n" + str(X_test))
    print("y_train " + "\n" + str(y_train))
    print("y_test " + "\n" + str(y_test))

    knn_alg(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, n_neighbors)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

First I extract the data from the csv file to a panda dataframe. Afterwards I extract the labels and split the dataset to train and test. In the last step I want to see if the fitted knn model can predict my test dataset but although I fitted the data the model throws the exception:

> NotFittedError("This KNeighborsClassifier instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method.",)

Do I fit the data in a false way? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you didn't fit the KNeighborsClassifier properly (for example, take a look at the example on the [Scikit-learn website](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html)).

Try this:

```
def knn_alg(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, N):
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=N)
    knn.fit(X_train, y_train)

    try:
        knn.predict(X_test)
    except NotFittedError as e:
        print(repr(e))
```

Comment: Sorry for this dumb fault... sometimes it helps if someone watches over your shoulder, thanks!